# How to change a labels text from outside the function in Python

Tags: python, function, tkinter, label

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make something as simple as displaying the temperature.  I can't get the temperature to display until I close the window, it goes into the loop get_outside_temp() but doesn't display anything until I break the loop then the window will be drawn.  See code below.

```
 #Import needed files
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import time


#define some variables
green = '#2BF720'
blue='#0CCAF0'
#blue = '#427BED'
font10 = "-family Newspaper -size 18 -weight bold -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"
font2 = "-family Newspaper -size 36 -weight bold -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"

#get outside temp and display it
def get_outside_temp():
     while True:
        tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416b113e1ff/w1_slave") 
        text = tfile.read() 
        tfile.close() 
        secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
        temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
        outside_temp = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
        outside_temp = round(outside_temp / 1000 ,1)
        print(outside_temp) #so I can see it's working
        #this is wherre I'm trying to display the temperature in the window.
        outside_temp_label.config(text = outside_temp)
        '''
        outside_temp_label = tk.Label(outside_frame, text=outside_temp, bg="Black", fg='White', font=font2)
        outside_temp_label.grid(padx=140, pady=75)
        '''
        time.sleep(5)


#create main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x480")
root.configure(bg="black")
root.title("Go Nad Go IV")

#create the frame for the outside
outside_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=230, width = 390, bg="black", 
relief="groove", highlightcolor = blue, highlightbackground=blue, highlightthickness = 2)
outside_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
outside_frame.grid_propagate(False)
outside_label = tk.Label(outside_frame, text="Outside Temperature", bg="Black", fg=blue, font=font10)
outside_label.grid(column=0,row=0)

#get the outside temp
tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416b113e1ff/w1_slave") 
text = tfile.read()
tfile.close() 
secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
outside_temp = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
outside_temp = round(outside_temp / 1000 ,1)

#display the temp
outside_temp_label = tk.Label(outside_frame, text=outside_temp, bg="Black", fg='White', font=font2)
outside_temp_label.grid(padx=140, pady=75)

get_outside_temp()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please add some sample data from file "w1_slave" that can help in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with accessing the label, it's that your entire program is unresponsive for 5 seconds during that `time.sleep(5)`. So, you've updated the label in memory, but it doesn't redrawn on the screen, because nothing at all is getting redrawn.

You can't sleep in a GUI program. If you want something to run every 5 seconds, you have three choices: use a background thread, drive the event loop manually, or just ask the GUI to run your code again in 5 seconds.

The last one is by far the simplest. In tkinter, it's spelled [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method), and you use it like this:

```
def get_outside_temp():

    # No while True loop here!

    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416b113e1ff/w1_slave") 
    text = tfile.read() 
    tfile.close() 

    # all your other existing code, except the sleep

    root.after(5000, callback=get_outside_temp)
```

In other words, instead of a function that runs forever, sleeping for 5 seconds at a time, we have a function that runs really quickly, asks to get run again in 5 seconds, and then returns to the event loop so other stuff can run (like redrawing the screen, responding to the mouse, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for that.  I did read up on  'after' and it looks like what I need except I received an error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I did manage to get it to work.
Instead of:
    root.after(5000, callback=get_outside_temp)
I had to use:
    root.after(5000, get_outside_temp)

Answer (score 0):

**fix:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import time


green = '#2BF720'
blue = '#0CCAF0'
font10 = "-family Newspaper -size 18 -weight bold -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"
font2 = "-family Newspaper -size 36 -weight bold -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"


def get_outside_temp():
   tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416b113e1ff/w1_slave") 
   text = tfile.read() 
   tfile.close() 
   secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
   temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
   outside_temp = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
   outside_temp = round(outside_temp / 1000 ,1)
   outside_temp_label.config(text = outside_temp)
   
   
   root.after(5000, get_outside_temp)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x480")
root.configure(bg="black")
root.title("Go Nad Go IV")

outside_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=230, width=390, bg="black", 
                        relief="groove", highlightcolor=blue, 
                        highlightbackground=blue, highlightthickness=2)
outside_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
outside_frame.grid_propagate(False)
outside_label = tk.Label(outside_frame, text="Outside Temperature", bg="Black", fg=blue, font=font10)
outside_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416b113e1ff/w1_slave") 
text = tfile.read() 
tfile.close() 
secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
outside_temp = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
outside_temp = round(outside_temp / 1000 ,1)

outside_temp_label = tk.Label(outside_frame, text=outside_temp, bg="Black", fg='White', font=font2)
outside_temp_label.grid(padx=140, pady=75)

get_outside_temp()
root.mainloop()
```

and the problem is because the `get_outside_temp()` **function continuously loops**. As a result, the Tkinter mainloop can't operate and refresh the window, code is constantly fetching the temperature.

**before:**

```
#get outside temp and display it

def get_outside_temp():
   while True:
      tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416b113e1ff/w1_slave") 
      text = tfile.read() 
      tfile.close() 
      secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
      temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
      outside_temp = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
      outside_temp = round(outside_temp / 1000 ,1)
      print(outside_temp) #so I can see it's working
      #this is wherre I'm trying to display the temperature in the window.
      outside_temp_label.config(text = outside_temp)
      '''
      outside_temp_label = tk.Label(outside_frame, text=outside_temp, bg="Black", fg='White', font=font2)
      outside_temp_label.grid(padx=140, pady=75)
      '''
      time.sleep(5)
```

**after:**

```
def get_outside_temp():
   tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416b113e1ff/w1_slave") 
   text = tfile.read() 
   tfile.close() 
   secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
   temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
   outside_temp = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
   outside_temp = round(outside_temp / 1000 ,1)
   print(outside_temp) #so I can see it's working
   outside_temp_label.config(text = outside_temp)
   
   # run again in 5 seconds
   root.after(5000, get_outside_temp)
```

**alternative variants how to do this:**

***threading -***

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

def long_running_task():
    time.sleep(5)  # simulating a long task
    root.after(0, update_gui)

def update_gui():
    label.config(text="Task Completed using a Thread!")

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Starting Task...")
label.pack()
thread = threading.Thread(target=long_running_task)
thread.start()
root.mainloop()
```

***event loop -***

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Starting Task...")
label.pack()

for _ in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)  # simulating work being done over time
    root.update()  # manually driving the event loop

label.config(text="Task Completed by driving the event loop manually!")
root.mainloop()
```

***periodic triggering -***

```
import tkinter as tk

def periodic_task(counter):
    if counter <= 0:
        label.config(text="Task Completed using after!")
    else:
        label.config(text=f"Task running... {counter} seconds left")
        root.after(1000, periodic_task, counter-1)

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Starting Task...")
label.pack()
root.after(1000, periodic_task, 5)  # starting the periodic task
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).